Prevent Datatable page jumping to page 1 after for instance row deletion
I've encountered an issue with renderDT from the DataTables package in my Shiny app. Occasionally, I need to delete one or more rows from the table. While there's a helpful example for row deletion (https://github.com/stefaneng/Shiny-DeleteRowsDT/blob/master/app.R), which I used as a starting point, I found that when a row is deleted, renderDT causes the app to jump back to page one, which can be disruptive when there are multiple pages.
I attempted to use DT::replaceData as suggested in this post, but it didn't work as I expected, probably because the table dimensions were affected.
I've used below a solution (inspired by this post) that involves running selectPage after renderDT. Yet, the solution seems to work like 70 % of time. Any idea why and how to improve?
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Delete rows"),
  mainPanel(
    selectInput('datasetSelect',
                label = 'Select data',
                choices = c("mtcars", "iris", "faithful")),
    uiOutput('undoUI'),
    DT::dataTableOutput("dtable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    deletedRows = NULL,
    deletedRowIndices = list()
  )
  
  pageNumber <- reactiveVal(1)

  observeEvent(input$datasetSelect, {
    rv$data <- switch (input$datasetSelect,
                       "mtcars" = mtcars,
                       "iris" = iris,
                       "faithful" = faithful
    )
    
    # Clear the previous deletions
    rv$deletedRows <- NULL
    rv$deletedRowIndices = list()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deletePressed, {
    rowNum <- parseDeleteEvent(input$deletePressed)
    dataRow <- rv$data[rowNum,]
    
    # Put the deleted row into a data frame so we can undo
    # Last item deleted is in position 1
    rv$deletedRows <- rbind(dataRow, rv$deletedRows)
    rv$deletedRowIndices <- append(rv$deletedRowIndices, rowNum, after = 0)
            
    # Delete the row from the data frame
    rv$data <- rv$data[-rowNum,, drop = FALSE]

    # On last page and removing the only remaining row?
last_element <- input$dtable_row_last_clicked %% input$dtable_state$length == 1 
last_page <- input$dtable_row_last_clicked == max(input$dtable_rows_all)

    # Add = 1 if the number of page is not affected by the deletion
    add <- ifelse(last_element && last_page, 0, 1)
    pageNumber(input$dtable_state$start/input$dtable_state$length+add) # set
    
    output$dtable <- DT::renderDT(deleteButtonColumn(isolate(rv$data), 'delete_button'))
  })
  
  # Set the page
  observeEvent (input$dtable_cell_clicked, {
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('dtable')
    selectPage(proxy, pageNumber())
  })  

  observeEvent(input$undo, {
    if(nrow(rv$deletedRows) > 0) {
      row <- rv$deletedRows[1, ]
      rv$data <- addRowAt(rv$data, row, rv$deletedRowIndices[[1]])
      
      # Remove row
      rv$deletedRows <- rv$deletedRows[-1,]
      # Remove index
      rv$deletedRowIndices <- rv$deletedRowIndices[-1]
    }
  })
  
  # Disable the undo button if we have not deleted anything
  output$undoUI <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(rv$deletedRows) && nrow(rv$deletedRows) > 0) {
      actionButton('undo', label = 'Undo delete', icon('undo'))
    } else {
      actionButton('undo', label = 'Undo delete', icon('undo'), disabled = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
  output$dtable <- DT::renderDT(
    # Add the delete button column
    isolate(deleteButtonColumn(rv$data, 'delete_button'))
  )
}

#' Adds a row at a specified index
#'
#' @param df a data frame
#' @param row a row with the same columns as \code{df}
#' @param i the index we want to add row at.
#' @return the data frame with \code{row} added to \code{df} at index \code{i}
addRowAt <- function(df, row, i) {
  # Slow but easy to understand
  if (i > 1) {
    rbind(df[1:(i - 1), ], row, df[-(1:(i - 1)), ])
  } else {
    rbind(row, df)
  }
  
}

#' A column of delete buttons for each row in the data frame for the first column
#'
#' @param df data frame
#' @param id id prefix to add to each actionButton. The buttons will be id'd as id_INDEX.
#' @return A DT::datatable with escaping turned off that has the delete buttons in the first column and \code{df} in the other
deleteButtonColumn <- function(df, id, ...) {
  # function to create one action button as string
  f <- function(i) {
    # https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html
    as.character(actionButton(paste(id, i, sep="_"), label = NULL, icon = icon('trash'),
                              onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue(\"deletePressed\",  this.id, {priority: "event"})'))
  }
  
  deleteCol <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), f))
  
  # Return a data table
  DT::datatable(cbind(delete = deleteCol, df),
                # Need to disable escaping for html as string to work
                escape = FALSE,
                editable = TRUE,
                options = list(pageLength  = 5,
                  # Disable sorting for the delete column
                  columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1, sortable = FALSE))
                ))
  
  
}

#' Extracts the row id number from the id string
#' @param idstr the id string formated as id_INDEX
#' @return INDEX from the id string id_INDEX
parseDeleteEvent <- function(idstr) {
  res <- as.integer(sub(".*_([0-9]+)", "\\1", idstr))
  if (! is.na(res)) res
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Does it help to call DT::renderDT with server = FALSE?

Thanks Jan. Yes, it does! Yet, I have to study the option more. Also, would love to understand why the inherit randomness of the original. Is it something to do with the order of time the observers are running?

Using a different trigger for observerEvent seems to be enough.
  # Set the page
  observeEvent (input$dtable_rows_all, {
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('dtable')
    selectPage(proxy, pageNumber())
  })  

I had several actions modifying the table, so in the end I used something along the lines of the code below:
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Delete rows"),
  mainPanel(
    selectInput('datasetSelect',
                label = 'Select data',
                choices = c("mtcars", "iris", "faithful")),
    uiOutput('undoUI'),
    DT::dataTableOutput("dtable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    deletedRows = NULL,
    deletedRowIndices = list()
  )
  
  pageNumber <- reactiveVal(1)
  trigger <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$datasetSelect, {
    rv$data <- switch (input$datasetSelect,
                       "mtcars" = mtcars,
                       "iris" = iris,
                       "faithful" = faithful
    )
    
    # Clear the previous deletions
    rv$deletedRows <- NULL
    rv$deletedRowIndices = list()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deletePressed, {
    rowNum <- parseDeleteEvent(input$deletePressed)
    dataRow <- rv$data[rowNum,]
    
    # Put the deleted row into a data frame so we can undo
    # Last item deleted is in position 1
    rv$deletedRows <- rbind(dataRow, rv$deletedRows)
    rv$deletedRowIndices <- append(rv$deletedRowIndices, rowNum, after = 0)
    
    # Delete the row from the data frame
    rv$data <- rv$data[-rowNum,, drop = FALSE]
    
    # On last page and removing the only remaining row?
    last_element <- input$dtable_row_last_clicked %% input$dtable_state$length == 1 
    last_page <- input$dtable_row_last_clicked == max(input$dtable_rows_all)
    
    # Add = 1 if the number of page is not affected by the deletion
    add <- ifelse(last_element && last_page, 0, 1) #
    pageNumber(input$dtable_state$start/input$dtable_state$length+add) # set
    
    trigger(trigger() + 1)
  })

  # Rerender
  observeEvent (trigger(), {
    output$dtable <- DT::renderDT(isolate(deleteButtonColumn(rv$data, 'delete_button')), server = TRUE)
  })
    
  # Set the page
  observeEvent (input$dtable_rows_all, {
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('dtable')
    # browser()
    # input$dtable_rows_selected
    # input$dtable_cells_selected
    # input$dtable_rows_all
    selectPage(proxy, pageNumber())
  })  

  observeEvent(input$undo, {
    if(nrow(rv$deletedRows) > 0) {
      row <- rv$deletedRows[1, ]
      rv$data <- addRowAt(rv$data, row, rv$deletedRowIndices[[1]])
      
      # Remove row
      rv$deletedRows <- rv$deletedRows[-1,]
      # Remove index
      rv$deletedRowIndices <- rv$deletedRowIndices[-1]
    }
  })
  
  # Disable the undo button if we have not deleted anything
  output$undoUI <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(rv$deletedRows) && nrow(rv$deletedRows) > 0) {
      actionButton('undo', label = 'Undo delete', icon('undo'))
    } else {
      actionButton('undo', label = 'Undo delete', icon('undo'), disabled = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
  output$dtable <- DT::renderDT(
    # Add the delete button column
    isolate(deleteButtonColumn(rv$data, 'delete_button'))
  )
}

#' Adds a row at a specified index
#'
#' @param df a data frame
#' @param row a row with the same columns as \code{df}
#' @param i the index we want to add row at.
#' @return the data frame with \code{row} added to \code{df} at index \code{i}
addRowAt <- function(df, row, i) {
  # Slow but easy to understand
  if (i > 1) {
    rbind(df[1:(i - 1), ], row, df[-(1:(i - 1)), ])
  } else {
    rbind(row, df)
  }
  
}

#' A column of delete buttons for each row in the data frame for the first column
#'
#' @param df data frame
#' @param id id prefix to add to each actionButton. The buttons will be id'd as id_INDEX.
#' @return A DT::datatable with escaping turned off that has the delete buttons in the first column and \code{df} in the other
deleteButtonColumn <- function(df, id, ...) {
  # function to create one action button as string
  f <- function(i) {
    # https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html
    as.character(actionButton(paste(id, i, sep="_"), label = NULL, icon = icon('trash'),
                              onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue(\"deletePressed\",  this.id, {priority: "event"})'))
  }
  
  deleteCol <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), f))
  
  # Return a data table
  DT::datatable(cbind(delete = deleteCol, df),
                # Need to disable escaping for html as string to work
                escape = FALSE,
                editable = TRUE,
                options = list(pageLength  = 5,
                  # Disable sorting for the delete column
                  columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1, sortable = FALSE, stateSave = TRUE))
                ))
  
  
}

#' Extracts the row id number from the id string
#' @param idstr the id string formated as id_INDEX
#' @return INDEX from the id string id_INDEX
parseDeleteEvent <- function(idstr) {
  res <- as.integer(sub(".*_([0-9]+)", "\\1", idstr))
  if (! is.na(res)) res
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

